# How to run jess file (.clp file) from windows CMD/ .bat file?

Tags: java, clips, jess

How to run a .clp file (jess) in windows cmd / .bat file? My current file looks like that:

```
(deftemplate Tree (slot current_node)(slot node_childrens))

(assert (Tree (current_node A)(node_childrens B,C,D)))
(assert (Tree (current_node B)(node_childrens E)))
(assert (Tree (current_node C)(node_childrens F,G)))

(defrule display_data
    
    (Tree (current_node ?cn))
    =>
    (printout t ?cn " ")
)

(run)
```

After running that the output in console looks like this:

```
C B A
```

How I can run that file from windows cmd and see the output there? For example if I have a python file called "myfile.py" I can run that with following command:

```
python myfile.py
```

How I can run a jess file in windows cmd / from a .bat file?

Answer (score 0):

To run `python myfile.py` inside of a batch file you could do:

myscript.bat:

```
path/to/python/executable path/to/python/file.py
pause
```

However if you have the `clips` command line tool installed you can do this:

script.bat

```
(load myfile.clp)
(reset)
(run)
```

And then call it using `clips -f2 script.bat` which can also be called from a batch file.